# Recognise Faces using opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm using `CascadeClassifier` to detect faces from an image. 
Here is how the iOS simulator detect faces.

[image]

I want to improve this by adding some more features. How can I improve this to recognise similar faces. For example if I use one person in a photo & again use another photo with the same person, how the application identify both of them are same?

Is there a method in opencv to do it? or can you please give me some tips to start learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object detection, and object recognition are two different games. You are wanting to do object recognition, therefore look at features in opencv. SIFT, SURF etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV's face recognition module:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/